# OSX hide window effect on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, effect, quartz-2d

Is it possible to 'easily' make on the iphone a MAC OSX hide window effect on a UIView? When I say easily, I mean using existing libraries or tools...

Thanks

Comment: By 'hide window' do you mean the genie effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such animation is built in to the iPhone SDK, you'd have to create it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use animations in UIKit to achieve this effect. Just set your frame or transformation to it's new location and call commitAnimations. You can adjust the speed, animation curve, and various other aspects to make your animation look like whatever effect you want. All of this is done with the UIView class.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Comment: Thanks but my problem is to find a specific animation (something which looks like the hide window animation in OSX)... Maybe I missed it but I didn't find it!